# Adding module dependency to Intellij Maven module

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven module, and then I have another maven module called shared, which has shared classes across all applications. Adding the shared maven module to the application maven module does not facilitate Intellij identifying classes in the shared module. What is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies should be specified inside your pom files, once IDEA imports them, it should parse the dependencies and set up the project automatically. Ensure that the scope is set properly, most likely it should be Compile in your case.

Dependencies that you set up manually inside IDEA module settings will be discarded on the next Maven project import.